# How to convert a decimal number to a binary number using recursive functions?

Tags: c

The process to convert a decimal number to a binary number is as follows:

Recursively divide the decimal number by 2, noting the remainder each time (which will be either 0 or 1).

- When you hit 0, write the remainders in reverse for the answer

For example, to convert 710 (base10) to its binary equivalent:

**Expected output:**

```
710 / 2 = 355, remainder 0
355 / 2 = 177, remainder 1
177 / 2 = 88, remainder 1
 88 / 2 = 44, remainder 0
 44 / 2 = 22, remainder 0
 22 / 2 = 11, remainder 0
 11 / 2 = 5, remainder 1
 5 / 2 = 2, remainder 1
 2 / 2 = 1, remainder 0
 1 / 2 = 0, remainder 1

710 (base10) = 1011000110 (base2)
```

Putting the remainders together (in reverse order) gives 71010 (base10) = 1011000110 (base2)

Write a recursive program to convert a decimal number to its binary equivalent.

**Example code that doesn't work:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*int convertToBinary() {

};

void printBinary() {

}*/

int main() {
    int base10 = 710;
    int base2;
    int remainder;

do {
    printf("%d / 2 = %d, remainder: %d\n", base10, base2, remainder);
    remainder = base10 % 2;
    base10 = base10 / 2;
    base2 = base10;
} while (base10 > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Incorrect output:**

```
710 / 2 = 32766, remainder: -333235520
355 / 2 = 355, remainder: 0
177 / 2 = 177, remainder: 1
88 / 2 = 88, remainder: 1
44 / 2 = 44, remainder: 0
22 / 2 = 22, remainder: 0
11 / 2 = 11, remainder: 0
5 / 2 = 5, remainder: 1
2 / 2 = 2, remainder: 1
1 / 2 = 1, remainder: 0
```

1. How do I correct the output?
2. How do I write these as individual functions?
3. How do I output the line that says "710 (base10) = 1011000110
   (base2)"?

Comment: What do you mean by `How do I write these as individual functions?`

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal for printBinary() "containing printf" and convertToBinary()

Comment: You haven't initialized the `base2` and `remainder` variables.

Comment: Just a quick reminder. There are no decimal or binary numbers. Numbers are numbers. There are decimal and binary *notations*. 5 and 101 are two notations for the same number. When you divide a number by two, the notation is irrelevant. You divide a number, not its notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here is the basic implementation:

   ```
   int toBinary(int x) {
       // base case
       if(x==0 || x==1)
           return x;
       printf("%d", toBinary(x/2));
       return x%2;
   }
   int main(){
       int num=710;
       printf("%d", toBinary(num));
   }
   ```
2. If you only want to print the line:

   ```
   void printBinary(int num) {
       printf("%d (base 10) = ", num);
       int lastBit = toBinary(num);
       printf("%d (base 2)", lastBit);
   }
   ```

Side note: A `recursive` function is a function that calls itself. Your example is a simple loop based program, not a recursive program.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    int base10 = 710;
    int remainder;

    while (base10 > 0)
    {
        printf("%d / 2 = %d, remainder: %d\n", base10, base10 / 2, base10 % 2);
        base10 = base10 / 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: op wants a recursive method.